# Use the Euclidean algorithm to show that 15m + 7 and 2m + 1 are relatively prime

Tags: discrete-mathematics, euclidean-algorithm

[image]

I am familiar with the Euclidean algorithm but I do not understand how to show that two numbers are relatively  prime if there is an m

Comment: The procedure will be very much the same as with numbers. To start, how many $2m+1$ can you remove from $15m+7$? In other words, find the greatest $k$ such that $(15m+7)-k(2m+1) \geq 0$. What are you left with?

Comment: Adding to @Théophile's comment, if you're struggling to see what's going on, you can always choose a couple small values of $m$ and perform the Euclidean algorithm on each pair *in parallel* to see the pattern of what's happening, e.g. when $m = 1$ it's $(22, 3)$, with $m = 2$ it's $(37, 5)$.

Comment: Well, look at what happens if you remove $2m+1$: you'll have $(15m+7)-(2m+1)=13m+6$. That's still big enough to remove another $2m+1$, so $(13m+6)-(2m+1)=11m+5$. Keep going.

Comment: To be clear, that is not sufficient to prove the claim, but it will give you a sense of what the general calculation/argument will look like.

Comment: K is 7, and I get that their difference is m.

Comment: Good. The next step in the Euclidean algorithm is to start again, this time using $2m+1$ and the value you found in the previous step $m$. What happens?

Comment: 7(2m+1) + m = 15m + 7  which is in fact correct, what else?

Comment: @SammyBlack's advice is good. Follow an example with actual numbers from start to finish, making sure you understand what the algorithm is doing along the way. Now that you see how the algebra works with polynomials, you can follow the same chain of reasoning. If you're still not sure, the best thing to do would be to edit your question to show the work you've done so far and where you're getting stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The key is the well known fact that if $a=qb+r$ where $0\le r\lt b$ then $(a,b)=(b,r)$ (equality of greatest common divisors). From which we have
$$15m+7=7(2m+1)+m\Rightarrow (15m+7,2m+1)=(2m+1,m)$$ and we are done because $(2m+1,m)=1$.